# How do i Save App state in Local Storage in Elm

Tags: javascript, elm

I want to cache the whole app state in the browser local storage. My model is a kind of check-out page consisting of various types , Here is the Model type alias :

```
type alias Model =
{ showCheckoutModal : Bool
, showAddressForm : Bool
, emailAddress : String
, address : Address
, selectedAddress : Maybe Address
, addresses : List Address
, name : String
, listings : List Listing
, shop : Maybe Shop
, shop_id : String
, shippingInfo : ShippingInfo
, selectedDestination : Maybe ShippingDestination
}
```

I have created the outgoing port and Incoming Port

```
port outgoing : OutgoingMsg -> Cmd msg

port incoming : (E.Value -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

So , I made some research and It can be done but all examples online are of simpler models , I havent seen any for a model as complex as mine. Please I appreciate any contribution , Thanks

Comment: I don't know elm, but localStorage can *only* store strings. So only values that can be serialized to a string and then parsed back into data can be stored in localStorage.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` to turn it into a string for storage before saving it and then `JSON.parse` to turn it back to a JSON object when reading it. Don't *rely* on localStorage, everything you put in there can disappear at any given time. If the complexity of your model is giving you any problems, please elaborate on what they are.

Comment: Yes That is on the javascript side , I have done this already... Now sending the whole model from elm to js is the problem, actually am working on a checkout page in elm and I want it to be stored in local storage and loaded back when the user visits the page again. I have shown the type aliases for all the content of  the model

Comment: You will want to read up on Elm's decoder/encoder APIs for how to turn your model into JSON when passing it through a port. The official guide mostly discuss decoders but the API docs for [Encode](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json.Encode) contains examples on how to use each part of it to build JSON structures.

Comment: Okay what I need is a little guidance or walk through on how to convert my model up there to a JSON Value except there is a way to store it in local storage without encoding it...